# Append individual (and multiple) sheets spread over multiple excel worksheets in a folder

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder containing 19 Excel worksheets with each worksheet containing 16 sheets inside it. While the name of the excel files are different, the name of individual sheets inside them is same i.e. they start from "Sheet 1" and go till "Sheet 16". What I have to do is append each sheet at the end of the next one and continue the same to get a new excel file containing only one sheet. (In other words, sheet 1 from file two (say, B) will be appended at the end of sheet 1 from file one (say, A) and sheet 1 from file three (say, C) will be appended at the end of the above two files containing sheet 1 from files A and B, respectively and so on untill every file is added).

I have tried VBA codes to extract each sheets and then rename each of them, convert them to CSV and then combine them. But this process takes too much time and there are many such folders. I would be grateful if I can get a VBA code, a python code or a R code to do all of these automatically (any of these will do. Explanations, if any, regarding the code will be helpful and appreciated. Thanks in advance).

Comment: It sounds as [Get & Transform](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/get-transform-in-excel-881c63c6-37c5-4ca2-b616-59e18d75b4de) could help you. But anyway, the question is too broad to give any specific advise.

Comment: To convert multiple excel sheet to CSV, I used the VBA code mentioned here:. https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5537-excel-batch-convert-to-csv.html ; To extract multiple sheets as individual files, I used the code mentioned here: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/785-excel-save-export-sheet-as-new-workbook.html

Comment: Is Get and Transform free? @Storax. And can you please guide me how to use that?

Comment: I have used the VBA codes I have mentioned above. But that involves manually changing every file name (since all the worksheets have same sheet numbers) so that I can put all of them in one folder and combine them using CMD. I don't know of any other way. If u can just suggest some VBA codes to be added to automate the process (to take all 19 files from the folder one by one) and change the names (by maybe suffixing file names to it), it will be more than enough.

Comment: @Rahul: Please see the link I provided. That should give you a start. Get & Transform belongs to Excel 365 and is a free add in/on for earlier versions.

Comment: So Workbook("A") will have 17 sheets with the new one renamed as "Sheet17"? And then, Workbook ("B") will have 16 or 17? (Sheet 1 - Sheet 17) or (Sheet 2 - Sheet 17)...

Comment: Are the 19 workbooks the only excel files in that folder?

Comment: Yes. They are the only excel sheets in that folder

Comment: @Garcia: No, sir. Each of the 19 worksheet (or excel file) has 16 sheets inside it, numbered sheet 1 to sheet 16. What I want is to append/add sheet 1 from each excel worksheet into one new excel sheet (can be named anything), sheet 2 from each excel worksheet into another sheet and so on until every has been appended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what you are after.  If so, I have adapted some code written for a similar problem to your requirement.

Open the first of these folders and create a macro enabled workbook within it.  The name of the workbook does not matter.

Within that workbook, create a worksheet named “Workbooks”.

Switch to the Visual Basic Editor.  I like to spread my code over several modules with a module per purpose.  You can include all the code below in a single module if you prefer providing there is only one `Option Explicit` statement.

Create a module and name it “LibExcel”.  The following code contains general routines from my library of Excel specific routines:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub FindLastRowCol(ByRef Wsht As Worksheet, ByRef RowLast As Long, _
                          ByRef ColLast As Long)

  ' Sets RowLast to the last row and ColLast to the last column with a value
  ' in worksheet Wsht.  Cells(RowLast, ColLast) need not contain a value.
  ' That is, the data in Wsht does not have to be rectangular.

  ' The motivation for coding this routine was the discovery that Find by
  ' previous row found a cell formatted as Merge and Center but Find by
  ' previous column did not. I had known that Find would miss merged
  ' cells but this was new to me.

  '   Dec16  Coded
  ' 31Dec16  Corrected handling of UserRange
  ' 15Feb17  SpecialCells was giving a higher row number than Find for
  '          no reason I could determine.  Added code to check for a
  '          value on rows and columns above those returned by Find
  ' 25Jun17  Found column with value above that found by Find. Fixed.

  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim ColLastFind As Long
  Dim ColLastOther As Long
  Dim ColLastTemp As Long
  Dim ColLeft As Long
  Dim ColRight As Long
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim RowIncludesMerged As Boolean
  Dim RowBot As Long
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim RowLastFind As Long
  Dim RowLastOther As Long
  Dim RowLastTemp As Long
  Dim RowTop As Long

  With Wsht

    Set Rng = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      RowLastFind = 0
      ColLastFind = 0
    Else
      RowLastFind = Rng.Row
      ColLastFind = Rng.Column
    End If

    Set Rng = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlValues, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
    Else
      If RowLastFind < Rng.Row Then
        RowLastFind = Rng.Row
      End If
      If ColLastFind < Rng.Column Then
        ColLastFind = Rng.Column
      End If
    End If

    Set Rng = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      RowLastOther = 0
      ColLastOther = 0
    Else
      RowLastOther = Rng.Row
      ColLastOther = Rng.Column
    End If

    Set Rng = .UsedRange
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
    Else
      If RowLastOther < Rng.Row + Rng.Rows.Count - 1 Then
        RowLastOther = Rng.Row + Rng.Rows.Count - 1
      End If
      If ColLastOther < Rng.Column + Rng.Columns.Count - 1 Then
        ColLastOther = Rng.Column + Rng.Columns.Count - 1
      End If
    End If

    If RowLastFind < RowLastOther Then
      ' Higher row found by SpecialCells or UserRange
      Do While RowLastOther > RowLastFind
        ColLastTemp = .Cells(RowLastOther, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If ColLastTemp > 1 Or .Cells(RowLastOther, 1).Value <> "" Then
          Debug.Assert False
          ' Is this possible
          ' Row after RowLastFind has value
          RowLastFind = RowLastOther
          Exit Do
        End If
        RowLastOther = RowLastOther - 1
      Loop
    ElseIf RowLastFind > RowLastOther Then
      Debug.Assert False
      ' Is this possible
    End If
    RowLast = RowLastFind

    If ColLastFind < ColLastOther Then
      ' Higher column found by SpecialCells or UserRange
      Do While ColLastOther > ColLastFind
        RowLastTemp = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ColLastOther).End(xlUp).Row
        If RowLastTemp > 1 Or .Cells(1, ColLastOther).Value <> "" Then
          'Debug.Assert False
          ' Column after ColLastFind has value
          ' Possible causes:
          '   * Find does not recognise merged cells
          '   ' Find does not examine hidden cells
          ColLastFind = ColLastOther
          Exit Do
        End If
        ColLastOther = ColLastOther - 1
      Loop
    ElseIf ColLastFind > ColLastOther Then
      Debug.Assert False
      ' Is this possible
    End If
    ColLast = ColLastFind

  End With

End Sub
Public Function WshtExists(ByRef Wbk As Workbook, ByVal WshtName As String)

  ' Returns True if Worksheet WshtName exists within
  '  * if Wbk Is Nothing the workbook containing the macros
  '  * else workbook Wbk

  ' 21Aug16  Coded by Tony Dallimore
  ' 14Feb17  Coded alternative routine that cycled through the existing worksheets
  '          matching their names against WshtName to check use of "On Error Resume Next"
  '          was the faster option. I needed to call the routines 6,000,000 times each to
  '          get an adequate duration for comparison. This version took 33 seconds while
  '          the alternative took 75 seconds.

  Dim WbkLocal As Workbook
  Dim Wsht As Worksheet

  If Wbk Is Nothing Then
    Set WbkLocal = ThisWorkbook
  Else
    Set WbkLocal = Wbk
  End If

  Err.Clear
  On Error Resume Next
  Set Wsht = WbkLocal.Worksheets(WshtName)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If Wsht Is Nothing Then
    WshtExists = False
  Else
    WshtExists = True
  End If

End Function
```

This code belongs in module “ModPrepare”.  Note the “Mod” is important.  The module contains a macro “Prepare”.  If you give a module and a macro the same name, you get obscure errors.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Prepare()

  ' Create list of workbooks (other than this workbook) in current folder

  Dim Path As String
  Dim RowWbks As Long
  Dim WbkName As String

  Path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

  With Worksheets("Workbooks")
    .Cells.EntireRow.Delete
    .Cells(1, 1).Value = "New workbook"
    .Cells(1, 2).Value = "Existing workbooks"
    .Range("A1:B1").Font.Bold = True

    RowWbks = 2

    WbkName = Dir$(Path & "*.xls*", vbNormal)

    Do While WbkName <> ""
      If WbkName <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
        .Cells(RowWbks, 2).Value = WbkName
        RowWbks = RowWbks + 1
      End If
      WbkName = Dir$
    Loop

    .Columns.AutoFit

  End With

End Sub
```

This code belongs in module “ModMerge”:

```
Option Explicit
  Const RowSrcDataFirst As Long = 3
Sub Merge()

  Dim ColCrnt As Long        ' Current column in either current worksheet
  Dim ColDestLast As Long    ' Last column in current destination worksheet
  Dim ColSrcLast As Long     ' Last column in current source worksheet
  Dim NumShtCrnt As Long     ' Number of current worksheet in source and destination workbooks
  Dim Path As String         ' Folder holding workbooks
  Dim RngSrc As Range        ' Range to be copied from current source worksheet
  Dim RowDestLast As Long    ' Last row in current destination worksheet
  Dim RowSrcCrnt As Long     ' Current row in current source worksheet
  Dim RowSrcLast As Long     ' Last row in current source worksheet
  Dim RowWbksCrnt As Long    ' Current row in worksheet "Workbooks"
  Dim WbkDest As Workbook    ' Reference to destination workbook
  Dim WbkSrc As Workbook     ' Reference to source workbook
  Dim WbkDestName As String  ' Name of destination workbook
  Dim WbkSrcName As String   ' Name of current source workbook
  Dim WshtDest As Worksheet  ' Reference to current destination worksheet
  Dim WshtSrc As Worksheet   ' Reference to current source worksheet
  Dim WshtWbks As Worksheet  ' Reference to worksheet "Workbooks"

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Set WshtWbks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Workbooks")
  Path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

  Set WbkDest = Workbooks.Add    ' Create new empty workbook

  RowWbksCrnt = 2
  WbkDestName = WshtWbks.Cells(RowWbksCrnt, 1).Value

  Do While True  ' Loop until find blank line in worksheet WorkBooks

    ' Get name of next source workbook
    With WshtWbks
      WbkSrcName = .Cells(RowWbksCrnt, 2).Value
      If WbkSrcName = "" Then Exit Do
      RowWbksCrnt = RowWbksCrnt + 1
    End With

    Debug.Print WbkSrcName;

    ' Open current source workbook
    Set WbkSrc = Workbooks.Open(Path & WbkSrcName, False, False)

    ' Copy worksheets "Sheet1" to "SheetN" from current
    ' source workbook to destination workbook
    NumShtCrnt = 1
    Do While True  '  Loop until SheetN does not exist
      If Not WshtExists(WbkSrc, "Sheet" & NumShtCrnt) Then
        ' No more worksheets
        Exit Do
      End If
      Debug.Print "  " & NumShtCrnt;
      With WbkSrc
        Set WshtSrc = .Worksheets("Sheet" & NumShtCrnt)
      End With
      ' Create destination worksheet if it does not exist
      With WbkDest
        If Not WshtExists(WbkDest, "Sheet" & NumShtCrnt) Then
          Set WshtDest = .Worksheets.Add
          With WshtDest
            .Name = "Sheet" & NumShtCrnt
            .Move After:=WbkDest.Worksheets("Sheet" & NumShtCrnt - 1)
          End With
        Else
          Set WshtDest = .Worksheets("Sheet" & NumShtCrnt)
        End If
      End With
      'Debug.Print "  " & "Sheet" & NumShtCrnt
      ' Find dimensions of source worksheet
      Call FindLastRowCol(WshtSrc, RowSrcLast, ColSrcLast)
      ' Find last row of destination worksheet; do not need last column
      Call FindLastRowCol(WshtDest, RowDestLast, ColDestLast)
      'Debug.Print "  Src " & RowSrcLast & " " & ColSrcLast
      'Debug.Print "  Dest " & RowDestLast & " " & ColDestLast
      With WshtSrc
        If RowDestLast = 0 Then
          ' First source worksheet to be copied to this destination sheet
          ' Include header rows
          Set RngSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(RowSrcLast, ColSrcLast))
          ' Copy column widths
          For ColCrnt = 1 To ColSrcLast
            WshtDest.Columns(ColCrnt).ColumnWidth = WshtSrc.Columns(ColCrnt).ColumnWidth
          Next
        Else
          ' Not first worksheet so exclude header rows
          Set RngSrc = .Range(.Cells(RowSrcDataFirst, 1), .Cells(RowSrcLast, ColSrcLast))
        End If
      End With
      RngSrc.Copy Destination:=WshtDest.Cells(RowDestLast + 1, 1)
      NumShtCrnt = NumShtCrnt + 1
    Loop  ' for every worksheet in current source workbook
    WbkSrc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Debug.Print
  Loop  ' for every source workbook

  WbkDest.Close SaveChanges:=True, Filename:=Path & WbkDestName

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Run macro “Prepare” to create a list in worksheet “Workbooks” like this:

[image: Worksheet "Workbooks" as created by macro Prepare]

I have four data workbooks in my folder; you have nineteen.  These workbooks are listed in the sequence created which may not be the sequence you want in the new workbook.  Amend this worksheet to look something like this:

[image: Worksheet "Workbooks" ready to control macro Merge]

The name in column A is the name to be given to the new workbook.  I have changed the sequence of names in column B to the output sequence I wish.  So the data from “Data B.xlsx” will come first then the data from “Data D.xlsx” and so on.  If the sequence of the data does not matter, leave column B alone.

Once worksheet “Workbooks” is as you wish, run macro “Merge”.  As the macro run, the following appears in the Immediate Window to provide a crude progress indicator:

```
Data B.xlsx  1  2  3
Data D.xlsx  1  2  3
Data A.xlsx  1  2  3
Data C.xlsx  1  2  3
```

I only have three worksheets per workbook.  The macro handles as many worksheets names “Sheets1” to “SheetsN” as it finds.  So for you, the list of sheet numbers will reach 16.  You will have 19 workbook names.  On my laptop, each source worksheet took a fraction of a second so the entire merge process took very little time.

Once you have checked the new data workbook, move the macro workbook to the next folder and run Prepare and Merge again.  Repeat for each folder.

The comments within the macros tell you what each block of code is doing but not what each statement is doing.  Come back with questions if necessary.

Comment: It is fast. But it is leaving out some cell values. 35 cells to be precise in each sheet. I checked the files today and I think it's misplacing some as well. I saw the process running and though it was very fast, I saw that it executes sheet 1, followed by sheet 10 to sheet 16 and then comes back to sheet 2 (till Sheet 9). I am not sure if this is contributing to misplaced cells or not. I got to know of it while looking at the file size (I had manually done one of them to compare them).

Comment: @Rahul.  Looking at my instructions, I have just noticed something I forgot to mention.  At the top of module ModMerge you will find: `Const RowSrcDataFirst As Long = 3`.  I tested my code with two header rows and forgot to tell you to change this statement if you have a different number of header rows.  If you have one header row, a value of 3 will skip every row 2 except from the first workbook.  This could explain the missing cells.  Change this `Const` to specify the first data row in your worksheets.  I apologise for forgetting to mention that.

Comment: I do not understand the sequence of work sheets you report.  The sequence you report is alphanumeric: 1, 10, 11, . . ., 16, 2, 3, . . . 9.  This is the sequence you would expect if the worksheets were sorted by name.  My code reads worksheet `"Sheet" & NumShtCrnt` where `NumShtCrnt` is 1, 2, 3, . . .  until the worksheet does not exist. I said the Immediate Window would display: WorkbookName  1  2  3 . . ..  Does it display this sequence of worksheet numbers?

Comment: Can you explain "misplacing some as well"?  In my tests, everything was where I expected it to be in the destination workbook.  I was expecting row 2 to be skipped because it was a header row in my test data.  Can you say more about your data so I can change my test data to be a better match.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I will try the first instruction out. As for the second, I was just letting you know. I was not aware what might be causing the problem. So I mentioned everything I thought was worth mentioning.

Comment: I agree, mention everything if you are not sure what is important. Come back after you have changed `RowSrcDataFirst` since that may fix everything. I use constants like this all the time so I did not think about them. (1) It means there is no 2 or 3 in my code so no need to wonder what they mean. A meaningful name like `RowSrcDataFirst` is immediately clear.  (2) The number of header rows can change. I have had to read carefully down a macro I inherited deciding which 2s referred to the first data row and which were something else. It is second nature for me to avoid literals like this

Comment: The reasons for "misplacing some cell values" was due to skipping two header rows.

Comment: I ran it again. It worked perfectly. Thanks, Tony. I thought no one will even understand my issue, let alone help me out.

Comment: You are welcome.  Consolidating data like this is a more frequent requirement than you might think.  As a result, I have a variety of routines I can adapt to a new requirement.